# How to create a DynamoDb with hash key of two columns and a column as a range key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to create a dynamodb table using two columns such as artist and song as HashKey and there is one column 'onYEAR' as Range Key. How can i do this, can anyone suggest me the keySchema.

```yaml
 KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: artist
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: song
            KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: onYEAR
            KeyType: RANGE
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to achieve by making **two** key attributes be the hash key.

If you want to both attributes **together** to be used as the key as a pair (called "compound" hash key in other databases), you can't - this isn't supported in DynamoDB. It can be approximated by creating one attribute containing the concatenation (for example) of the two keys.

If, however, you want your items to be retrievable by any **one** of the two keys together with the range key, then you need to pick one as the hash key, and the second one the hash key of a **global secondary index** (GSI).

Comment: Thanks sir. But I also need to have global secondary index (GSI) with completely different columns from CompositePrimaryKey.

//Here i need two columns Status, AssetsID as a part of hash key.

I need 



`code`
GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: Gsi-Index-Name
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: AssetsID-Status
//Here i need two columns Status, AssetLogId as a part of hash key.
              KeyType: HASH
`code`



Can i know how to do this. to have two hashkeys for GSI but not a range key. If range Key is needed what is the possibility for it

Comment: @Nadav Har'El: Is there any drawback of concatinating them into another column, using a separation char?

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answer states: you can't do that. But you can do different.

First of all the KEY must be unique. Regardless if you only used a hash or you using a composite key, the resulted key must be unique within the table. But I guess you already know that.

Secondly you need to understand the behaviour/function of each key. The hash key also called the partition key, because that is how ddb will partition your table. The range key is also called sort key, because ddb will sort the data within a partition by that key.

And it is important to model your table by knowing how you plan to access the data, because you want to use the hash to retrieve THE GROUP and the range to to search WITHIN the group.

So the hash key should be the key you want to group the items by and the range key should be something you want to filter the data by.

Using the artist/song/year example, let's say you want to access all the songs made by the artist, then you can query the artist only and ddb will return all the songs.

Let's say you also want to access the songs form an artist, but only the ones that starts with the letter 'A'.
Using the song as the range key allows you to do that.

But let's say you want more. You want to be able to list songs made only in a specific year. Then you want to create a LSI (local secondary index) where the hash key is the same, but you can create a different range key where you combine the year and song. If you would use only the year than it won't be unique, hence you add the song title to it. E.g.: '1996_aqua'
That will allow you to filter items which starts with 1996 so basically returning songs that made by a specific artist and made in a specific year.

So what I'm trying to say that when you design your keys in ddb you have to know how you want to access the data (access patterns), because that is the factor on how you should build those keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two or more columns by concatenating, and eventually hash the full string with MD5 into another column and use it as a hash-key.